# Fatal error when running starting rails server on rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rubymine

so I started creating a new rails application using rubymine. I have created the new rails app and have also created a model using the scaffold feature. However, whenever I try to start the rails server or run rake db:migrate, I get the following error "PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  role "Marcos" does not exist". I have tested the connection to my postgres db. The username and password are set to "postgres". Here is my database.yml file:

```
    # PostgreSQL. Versions 9.1 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On OS X with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On OS X with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: aaa_development

  # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
  # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
  # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
  # the same name as the operating system user that initialized the database.
  #username: aaa

  # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
  #password:

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  #host: localhost

  # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
  # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
  #port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # Defaults to warning.
  #min_messages: notice

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: aaa_test

# As with config/secrets.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: aaa_production
  username: aaa
  password: <%= ENV['AAA_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

I have the gem installed but I cant figure out what to do anymore. I know the message basically says that the role cannot be found. How do add the role? how do I check the current roles? Any help would be much appreciated thank you!

Comment: Try to specify username and password in the development section

Comment: Thank you Vasilisa! That got rid of that error. Now It is saying "ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "aaa_development" does not exist) wasnt that created when the aaa project was created?

Comment: You need to run `rake db:create`

Comment: Ok so I ran rake db:migrate and it keep telling me that error. I went ahead and commented out this part "  database: aaa_development" and it now seems to be working. Why didnt I need that line?

Comment: Try to run `rake db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:migrate`

Comment: `database: aaa_development` - this is a name of your db in the dev env for this project. You really need this line :)

Comment: Thank you so much Vasilisa! That worked! But why did it start working after commenting out that line? it even lets me run rake db:migrate

Comment: Because it worked with you default Postgres db `postgres` :)